# Migrating virtualenv and Github between computers

Tags: python, git, github, virtualenv

I primarily work these days with Python 2.7 and Django 1.3.3 (hosted on Heroku) and I have multiple projects that I maintain.  I've been working on a Desktop with Ubuntu running inside of a VirtualBox, but recently had to take a trip and wanted to get everything loaded up on my notebook.  But, what I quickly discovered was that virtualenv + Github is really easy for creating projects, but I struggled to try and get them moved over to my notebook.  The approach that I sort of came up with was to create new virtualenv and then clone the code from github.  But, I couldn't do it in the folder that I really wanted because it would say the folder is not empty.  So, I would clone it to a tmp folder than them cut/paste the everthing into where I really wanted it.  Not TERRIBLE, but I just feel like I'm missing something here and that it should be easier.  Maybe clone first, then mkvirtualenv?

It's not a crushing problem, but I'm thinking about making some more changes (like getting ride of the VirtualBox and just going with a Dual boot system) and it would be great if I could make it a bit smoother.  :)

Finally, I found and read a few posts about moving git repos between computers, but I didn't see any dealing with Virtualenv (maybe I just missed it).

EDIT:  Just to be clear and avoid confusion, I'm not try to "move" the virtualenv.  I'm just talking about best way to create a new one.  Install the packages, and then clone the repo from github.

Comment: "But, I couldn't do it in the folder that I really wanted because it would say the folder is not empty." -- Are you making the virtualenv your git repository? As in, are `bin/` (the one with `activate`) and `.git` in the same directory?

Comment: Yes...  .git, bin, requirements.txt are all in the same level.  Bin is not checked into the repo.  I then have a folder named "src" at the same level and below that is where my source is contained.

Answer (score 14):

The only workflow you should need is:

```
git clone repo_url somedir
cd somedir
virtualenv <name of environment directory>
source <name of environment directory>/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This assumes that you have run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` (while the venv is activated) to list all the virtualenv-pip-installed libraries and checked it into the repo.

Answer (score 10):

That's because you're not even supposed to move virtualenvs to different locations on one system (there's relocation support, but it's experimental), let alone from one system to another. Create a new virtualenv:

- Install virtualenv on the other system
- Get a `requirements.txt`, either by writing one or by storing the output of `pip freeze` (and editing the output)
- Move the requirements.txt to the other system, create a new virtualenv, and install the libraries via `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
- Clone the git repository on the other system

For more advanced needs, you can create a bootstrapping script which includes virtualenv + custom code to set up anything else.

EDIT: Having the root of the virtualenv and the root of your repository in the same directory seems like a pretty bad idea to me. Put the repository in a directory inside the virtualenv root, or put them into completely separate trees. Not only you avoid git (rightfully -- usually, everything not tracked by git is fair game to delete) complaining about existing files, you can also use the virtualenv for multiple repositories and avoid name collisions.

Comment: Just as a note, I'm not moving...  I am creating a new virtualenv.  I will edit the original question to make that more clear.

Comment: Also...  what what do you do about the cloning?  For me, git complains because the destination folder is not empty.  It seems like Matt B answer handles that, but you don't.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidS usually you want to create a virtualenv *inside* each of your projects, i.e. inside the cloned directory. This way you can have separate, isolated virtualenvs for multiple projects all on the same machine.

Comment: @mattb...  I'm not sure if I'm making myself clear.  I have a folder called .venvs where all of my virutualenvs live.  .venv is my WORKON_HOME (for virtualenvwrapper).  Inside of there, I have venv1, venv2, etc.  Inside of each one of these, lives a .git repo.  Make sense?

Comment: @DavidS I think I understand your setup. What I don't understand is how it's relevant here. The sole problem is the git repo containing the components of the virtualenv (is this the case? I asked before, but perhaps I wasn't clear enough). Why not have a separate directory (I use `~/devel/`) for repositories?

Comment: @delnan...  maybe that's the part that I've been missing.  Adding one more directory under my virtualenv to make cloning the repo a little bit easier.  Like I said, what I've been doing is cloing to a seperate dir and then moving it over.  It should like you just handle it a bit better than I am.  I will try your idea on the next project.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to scripting creating a new virtualenv, you should make a requirements.txt file that has all of your dependencies (e.g Django1.3), you can then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and this will install all of your dependencies for you.

You can even have pip create this for you by doing `pip freeze > stable-req.txt` which will print out you dependencies as there are in your current virtualenv. You can then keep the requirements.txt under version control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand that part.  I would like to point out that it can be a bit challenging with a brand new machine because you will keep running into to problems with modules that need to be built (such as psycopg2, django-pylibmc-sasl).  But, once you get all of the "dev" files installed, then install from the requirements.txt file is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I saw this which can help you get around the modules that need to be built: http://blip.tv/djangocon/taming-dependencies-with-pip-5582996 its worth a watch

Comment: @DavidS can't you install those dependencies with pip? I can find both with `pip search`. Putting them in the `requirements.txt` means less work is required for new devs/setups.

Comment: @mattb ...  I don't know.  I'll that I'm doing is using pip freeze > requirements.txt.  I've never used pip search.

Comment: that video i referenced above talks about it, I haven't tried it myself but it seems like a great solution as @mattb says

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about a virtualenv is that you can describe how to make one, and you can make it repeatedly on multiple platforms.

So, instead of cloning the whole thing, clone a method to create the virtualenv consistently, and have that in your git repository. This way you avoid platform-specific nasties.

Comment: Interesting...  but, please forgive my ignorance, I'm not sure that I understand exactly.  Could you give any more details?  Or could you provide a link?  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I think he means: use a requirements.txt file and create a shell script that runs the last part of [matt b answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12410239/1521064): `virtualenv` to create, `source` to activate, `pip` to install.